# Visual Code: open project with zero open files, collapsed Explorer tree

Tags: visual-studio-code

goofy question, but I really want to stop Visual Code from resuming a project configuration when I reopen that project, meaning: no open files, collapsed Explorer tree, etc. Just as if I'd never opened the project before. This is different than `window.restoreWindows` as its project specific. I just want a fresh start every time I open a project w/o having to manually close a bunch of files. Is this possible?

Comment: "_Just as if I'd never opened the project before_" is that really your question? Because there's a _lot_ more to what VS Code remembers about a workspace than just open files and the expand/collapse state of the explorer tree. What are you really asking for? Be careful what you wish for. I can answer either question but I'm not answering until I know what the question _really_ is.